# Report comes two pages when using subreport

Tags: java, jasper-reports, inputstream, ireport, subreport

I have a problem when using a subreport in my report.
I have a query which produced only one record. And I've arranged for one record displayed one page.

When there is a subreport, it prints 2 pages, wherein the second page blank. And I see the following exception:

```
Apr 01, 2013 5:45:25 PM net.sf.jasperreports.view.JRViewer paintPage
SEVERE: Page paint error.
net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRRuntimeException: net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRException: Image read failed.
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.export.draw.PrintDrawVisitor.visit(PrintDrawVisitor.java:143)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.export.draw.PrintDrawVisitor.visit(PrintDrawVisitor.java:57)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRTemplatePrintImage.accept(JRTemplatePrintImage.java:442)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.export.draw.FrameDrawer.draw(FrameDrawer.java:251)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.export.draw.FrameDrawer.draw(FrameDrawer.java:199)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.export.JRGraphics2DExporter.exportPage(JRGraphics2DExporter.java:273)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.export.JRGraphics2DExporter.exportReportToGraphics2D(JRGraphics2DExporter.java:246)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.export.JRGraphics2DExporter.exportReport(JRGraphics2DExporter.java:184)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.view.JRViewer.paintPage(JRViewer.java:2104)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.view.JRViewer$PageRenderer.paintComponent(JRViewer.java:2254)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paint(JComponent.java:1054)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paintChildren(JComponent.java:887)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paint(JComponent.java:1063)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paintChildren(JComponent.java:887)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paint(JComponent.java:1063)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paintChildren(JComponent.java:887)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paint(JComponent.java:1063)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paintChildren(JComponent.java:887)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paint(JComponent.java:1063)
    at javax.swing.JViewport.paint(JViewport.java:731)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paintChildren(JComponent.java:887)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paint(JComponent.java:1063)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paintChildren(JComponent.java:887)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paint(JComponent.java:1063)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paintToOffscreen(JComponent.java:5221)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager$PaintManager.paintDoubleBuffered(RepaintManager.java:1512)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager$PaintManager.paint(RepaintManager.java:1443)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager.paint(RepaintManager.java:1236)
    at javax.swing.JComponent._paintImmediately(JComponent.java:5169)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paintImmediately(JComponent.java:4980)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager$3.run(RepaintManager.java:796)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager$3.run(RepaintManager.java:784)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager.paintDirtyRegions(RepaintManager.java:784)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager.paintDirtyRegions(RepaintManager.java:757)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager.prePaintDirtyRegions(RepaintManager.java:706)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager.access$1000(RepaintManager.java:62)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager$ProcessingRunnable.run(RepaintManager.java:1651)
    at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:251)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:727)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$200(EventQueue.java:103)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:688)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:686)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:697)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:242)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:161)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:150)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:146)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:138)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:91)
```

I've been looking expcetion above problems, as InputStream or no image. And the above exception because the second page that appears. Where the second page I did not expect.

In the subreport, I made 2 columns to display the image, and I put it on pageHeader and columnHeader band. So there are 4 pictures, 2 in pageHeader and 2 more in columnHeader.

Any suggestions? Please help, thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

check the size of the image and also check the height of pageHeader and columnHeader  band.

Comment: I already set image width=150 and height=113 but when i generate report , it width=200 and height=149 any suggestions? :(

Comment: add width,height,left and top these four parameter.you just share your jrxml file ie. the xml code

Answer (score 1):

Check your cache properties on images. `isUsingCache="true"` solved the problem for me.